# How to write large files to SQL Server FILESTREAM?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stream

I'm having a problem writing *large* amounts of data to FILESTREAM column on SQL Server. Specifically, smallish files around 1.5-2GB are handled fine, but when the size reaches 6GB and up, I'm getting *intermittent* `IOException` "The handle is invalid" on `.CopyTo()` towards the end of the transfer.

I've thought about writing the data in chunks, but SQL Server copies the backing file for the field before allowing to append data to it, which destroys the performance for large files completely.

Here's the code:

```
public long AddFragment (string location , string description = null) 
{
    const string sql = 
        @"insert into [Fragment] ([Description],[Data]) " +
            "values (@description,0x); " +
         "select [Id], [Data].PathName(), " +
             "GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() " +
         "from " +
             "[Fragment] " +
         "where " +
             "[Id] = SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

    long id;

    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(
        TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
            new TransactionOptions {
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
            })) 
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(m_ConnectionString)) 
        {
            connection.Open();

            byte[] serverTx;
            string serverLocation;

            using (var command = new SqlCommand (sql, connection)) 
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@description", 
                    SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = description;

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader ()) 
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    id = reader.GetSqlInt64(0).Value;
                    serverLocation = reader.GetSqlString (1).Value;
                    serverTx = reader.GetSqlBinary (2).Value;
                }
            }

            using (var source = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Open, 
                FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, 
                FileOptions.SequentialScan))
            using (var target = new SqlFileStream(serverLocation, 
                serverTx, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                source.CopyTo ( target );
            }
        }

        scope.Complete();
    }

    return id;
}
```

Comment: Maybe look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933972(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: There's a generic example there that writes _9_ bytes to the field.

Comment: Maybe a timeout on the connection. Did you try increasing connection timeouts for example. BTW, just wondering, why are you using SQL Server for files that large? Is this becoming a common practice on SQL Server these days?

Comment: There are timeouts everywhere. On the SqlCommand as well as on the transaction (the 1-day timeout you specified does not work because the default max. timeout is 10min. You need to edit some config file to get around this).

Comment: You need to use BufferedStream for large file handlings and it has been workable too in enterprise application.

Comment: @Kathir: all that would do for `.CopyTo` call is add some overhead.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you use [BufferedStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx) Class around your [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) class.

Also make sure you are setting the [WriteTimeOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream.writetimeout.aspx) property on the [SqlFileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc452018.aspx) class.

Here you find a really good post that explain everything about SqlFileStream http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/

Comment: Despite the docs, WriteTimeout is not supported and will throw an InvalidOperationException from the underlying Stream, at least in 4.0

Comment: that is a shame, also just to point out its not needed to use bufferedstream on a FileStream as from recent version of the .net buffering functionality has been added to FileStream.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by some of the comments, the problem is probably a transaction timeout. You could verify this by running SQL Server Profiler and watching for your transaction to be rolled back.

Unless otherwise specified, the machine.config has a default maxTimeout of 10 minutes, which cannot be overridden via code.  To increase the max timeout, add the following to the configuration setting of your machine.config

```
<system.transactions>
  <machineSettings maxTimeout="00:30:00" />
</system.transactions>
```